# вероятности в java

Tags: java

Как в java работать с вероятностями? Допустим, у меня есть переменная `int x`, которая с вероятностью 50% равна 1; c вероятностью 30% равна 2; и 
c вероятностью 20% равна 3. Желательно без использования дополнительных переменных.

Comment: ты про рандом спрашиваешь или как ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public int getRandomInt(){
  double x = new Random().nextDouble();
  if(x < 0.2) return 3;
  else if(x >= 0.2 && x < 0.5) return 2;
  else return 1;
}
```

Думаю ты понял по какому принципу можно это делать. Есть еще нормальное распределение, `nextGausian()`. А так можешь поискать в интернет кучу библиотек с теорвером и матстатом. Там распределения, отклонения, интерполяции и т.д.

Comment: `else if(x >= 0.2 && x < 0.5)` => `else if(x < 0.5)`

Comment: я понимаю, так просто более нагляднее

Comment: А на мой взгляд, наоборот.